# Bash =~ loosing BASH_REMATCH contents at the cmd prompt OS X

Tags: bash, macos

Suppose I have a (silly example) script:

```
#!/bin/bash
st="one two three"
[[ $st =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+) ]]
for i in "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

It works as expected -- it prints:

```
one two three
one
two
three
```

Which is the overall match then each match group. HOWEVER, if I go to the shell and type:

```
$ st="one two three"
$ [[ $st =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+) ]]
$ for i in "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
> do
>    echo "$i"
> done
```

It prints:

```
w
```

If I do

```
$ [[ $st =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:alpha:]]+) ]] && arr=( "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}" )
```

I can then loop through the copy of `BASH_REMATCH` in `arr` showing that the match works OK. But something seems to happen to `BASH_REMATCH` in the interactive shell use on Bash 3.2. right after a successful match.

This is the default `3.2.57(1)-release` on macOS Sierra 10.12.1

If I fire up Bash 4.4, it all works OK.

Ideas?

---

Edit

Gordon Davis is correct: it has to do with an Apple utility using `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` as part of displaying the prompt.

Easy to demonstrate:

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
/Users/andrew
w
$ cd /tmp
$ pwd && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
/tmp
p
```

Then if I run Apple's bash with no `rc` file:

```
$ /bin/bash  --norc
bash-3.2$ pwd && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
/tmp

bash-3.2$
```

(There is a blank line for `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` there...)

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem with my Mac OS X 10.10.5, GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14). Maybe try with no profile?

Comment: I tried in a generic account, so no profile other than Apple default of `/etc/bashrc`  -- same deal. Tried on another computer with a different profile -- same deal.

Comment: Bizarre. I cannot reproduce either on Sierra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because Apple's default bash init file has a fancy function to define the prompt, and it recomputes it every time the prompt needs to be displayed, *and* that function uses `=~` and therefore replaces the previous contents of `BASH_REMATCH`. See the definition of `update_terminal_cwd` in /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal (which is sourced by /etc/bashrc).

If this is causing you trouble, I think it's safe to undefine the function with `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` (that leaves the function defined, but it is not used).

BTW, `BASH_REMATCH` wound up being set to "w" because the function steps through your working directory character by character, URL-encoding them as it goes. "w" is apparently the last character in your working directory.

EDIT: looking at the function, it doesn't actually do anything with the prompt; it sets the folder section of the Terminal window title bar. If you unset PROMPT_COMMAND, it'll stop updating the window title.

Comment: Genius! Yup if I fire up a brand new shell and type `$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` I get the last character of the current working directory.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that feature. I use iTerm instead of Terminal, so there is no additional setup being done.

Comment: @chepner Ah, I wondered why you couldn't repro it; webb is probably also using another terminal program. /etc/bashrc sources `/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM` (if it exists), and /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal is the only one that exists.

Comment: i use iterm and also have a custom prompt. awesome investigation, gordon!