# Bash Regex Capture

Tags: regex, linux, bash, macos

I'd like to capture portions of strings that match a regular expression (see code below). For example given: `apply plugin: 'java'` I'd like to capture `java`.

I've put together the following regex. When I execute the code below (on Linux or Mac OS) a match is found, but the `BASH_REMATCH` array is empty (i.e. length of zero).

Does anyone know what is wrong with the regex and/or its application?

```
regex="^[[:space:]]*apply[[:space:]]*plugin:[[:space:]]*'([[:alpha:]]+)'[[:space:]]*$"

if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "Match count is ${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}."
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "No match."
fi
```

Comment: Can your show output of `declare -p line`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/DzvKzX, the array in Linux is not empty.

Comment: This might have the answer: [Bash =~ loosing BASH_REMATCH contents at the cmd prompt OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456012/bash-loosing-bash-rematch-contents-at-the-cmd-prompt-os-x).

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: @glennjackman GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)

Comment: hmm, `=~` and `BASH_REMATCH` were introduced in version 3.0 ([CHANGES file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.4))

Comment: Try echo-ing something in an else block: perhaps your $line does not match.

Comment: *＋1* for asking an Bash question that has to do with programming and development.

Comment: In bash 4.1.17, the ouput is the expected `apply plugin: 'java' java`

Comment: @glennjackman I changed the code to echo in both match and no-match cases. I continue to get a "match" but no capture. For example, with the above changes, I get `Match count is 0.` followed by a blank line.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to reproduce this as posted on macOS. You might have a debug trap or similar set.

To help debug this, please edit your question to include:

1. The complete script that you run (i.e. including whatever populates `$line`)
2. The complete command you use to run it, and the complete output
3. bash xtrace (`-x`) output

I expanded your code into a MCVE using information from your comments:

```
$ cat myfile
regex="^[[:space:]]*apply[[:space:]]*plugin:[[:space:]]*'([[:alpha:]]+)'[[:space:]]*$"

line="apply plugin: 'java'"

if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "Match count is ${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}."
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "No match."
fi
```

Then I ran it like this and got expected output:

```
$ bash myfile
Match count is 2.
java
```

Here's the output with debug info on:

```
$ bash -x myfile
+ regex='^[[:space:]]*apply[[:space:]]*plugin:[[:space:]]*'\''([[:alpha:]]+)'\''[[:space:]]*$'
+ line='apply plugin: '\''java'\'''
+ [[ apply plugin: 'java' =~ ^[[:space:]]*apply[[:space:]]*plugin:[[:space:]]*'([[:alpha:]]+)'[[:space:]]*$ ]]
+ echo 'Match count is 2.'
Match count is 2.
+ echo java
java
```

Here's system info:

```
$ uname -a && bash --version
Darwin hostname 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I can add reproduce the same results by e.g. adding `trap '[[ a =~ b ]]' DEBUG` to the script. If you're doing something like that, it will show up in the `-x` output.

Comment: Although this is really an extended comment, +1 for the detailed debugging help offered.